# ROC curves and logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, binary-data, roc

I understand that roc curves and logistic regression both classify, but how do I connect logistic regression with classification and ROC the curve?

Comment: a roc curve does not classify. it shows tpr and fpr for all possible thresholds. you can use roc curves to evaluate your logistic regression classifier.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.